# Positioning element exactly over other element in css

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have some elements sharing certain css. Now I would like one element to have a covering div over it with some text in it. An example can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FBjQV/1/). Currently it's kind of 'guessed' in place, but you can see differences between browsers so I doubt getting the pixels exactly right would change anything.

Currently, my method to get this is inserting a `<div>` with the same properties, but it's a lot of duplicate code and isn't perfect.

Here's the **HTML**:

```
<!-- regular non-locked element -->
<a href='#' class='level yellow'>
    <h1>Level 1</h1>
    <div class='score'>score</div>
    <h2>248</h2>
    <input type='text' value='20' class='dial' />
</a>

<!-- locked element -->
<div class='level yellow'>
    <h1>Level 1</h1>
    <div class='score'>score</div>
    <h2>0</h2>
    <input type='text' value='0' class='dial' />
    <div class='locked'><br /><br /><br />You still need to unlock this level!</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.level {
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    width:150px;
    height:220px;
    padding:10px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color:transparant;
    color:#8C9695;
    margin:15px auto 0px auto;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
    text-align:center;
}
.level:hover:not(> .locked){
    color: white;
}
.locked {
    background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    width:172px;
    height:242px;
    position:relative;
    top:-135px;
    left:-10px;
    border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    z-index:20;
    cursor:default;
    transition:0.3s;
    color:transparent;
    text-align:center;
}
.locked:hover{
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can position elements exactly over each other by giving the underlying element `position:relative` and the overlay element as a child of it with `position:absolute` and `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` properties all as `0`. For example:

```
.level {
    position:relative;
}

.locked {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
    background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    z-index:20;
    cursor:default;
    transition:0.3s;
    color:transparent;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you only need one element - just hide/unhide the locked div, or change the class of the normal element to a locked class, or fade one into the other or....

In short there are a lot of ways to do this.

Comment: Well the problem is the exact positioning. Because the bottom part of my locked element is used elsewhere on the page it would be handy not to have to rewrite it. Also, the locked one should display the content of the element underneath it, but I can't get it positioned exactly over the other element...